# Settings for moment datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set date and time picker using the moment js for bootstrap. 
First I have set this.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                      <input id="begindateTime" class="form-control has-feedback-left"  placeholder="Begin Date Time" type="text" >                     
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Next I have ensure this.

```
<!-- daterangepicker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Next I have set this

```
<script>

        $('#begindateTime').datepicker();

   </script>
```

The issue its showing datetimepicker  is not a function? I need a both date and time with the hour and minute selection. What could be I am missing?

Comment: Use `$('#begindateTime').datetimepicker();`

Comment: ***[Here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)*** is its documentaion....

Comment: I tried that I get this error now Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Mine is actually moment datetimepicker you gave the documentation for https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: For [DateRange Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), use `$('#begindateTime')‌​.daterangepicker();`

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: You need to add [Following](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage) files.

Comment: I have updated all my files. Now all works fine. The issue is <script>
   $(function() {
      
     $('#begindateTime').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false
    
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected");
});
  }) 
   </script> when I click apply the time does not appear in the text box but the date appear? What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDN :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"></script>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
         <h6>datetimepicker2</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

**Use This Code..**

This will useful for you..

Comment: Thank you but my other one is working just now the its not picking the time in.